# Format a standard ("Norm") in Biblatex -- show publication month in ISO style

Tags: biblatex, date

I'm trying to set my own style for standards documents ('Normen' in German). I have copied most of it from report and it works quite well, except the month, which is formatted locally (even in `\printfield{month}` and returns `Okt. 2023`; however, it should be ISO style `2023-10`.

I can use `date=iso`, but that applies to all dates, not just the ones for the `@norm`-entries. How can I remedy that?

Currently:
[image]

Alternatively I can use `\printfield{month}`, but that returns the month also already formatted locally for my language as `Okt.`, but I want `10`, with a leading zero, if the month only has one digit. In programming languages the date would be `YYYY-MM`, has Latex something similar to this?

Desired result:
[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
    @norm{lnorm,
        title   = {Information und Dokumentation -- Richtlinien für Titelangaben und Zitierung von Informationsressourcen},
        type    = {DIN ISO},
        number  = 690,
        date    = {2013-10},
        doi = {10.31030/2054156},
    }
\end{filecontents}
% , date=iso
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{norm}{%
    \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
    \usebibmacro{begentry}%
    %\usebibmacro{author}%
    %\setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
    \printfield{type}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \printfield{number}%
    \setunit*{\addcolon}%
    \usebibmacro{date}%
    %\printfield{year}-\printfield{month}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{title}%
    %\newunit
    %\printlist{language}%
    %\newunit\newblock
    %\usebibmacro{byauthor}%
    %\newunit\newblock
    %\usebibmacro{institution+location}%
    %\newunit\newblock
    %\printfield{version}%
    %\newunit\newblock
    %\printdate
    %\bibdatetimesep
    %\usebibmacro{date}%
    %\newunit
    %\printfield{note}%
    %\newunit\newblock
    %\usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
    %\newunit
    %\printfield{pagetotal}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isrn}}
    {}%
    \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
    %\newunit\newblock
    %\usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
    %\setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
    %\usebibmacro{pageref}%
    %\newunit\newblock
    %\iftoggle{bbx:related}
    %{\usebibmacro{related:init}%
    %   \usebibmacro{related}}
    %{}%
    \usebibmacro{finentry}
}

\begin{document}
Text~\cite[6]{lnorm}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: Don't load both `babel` (with `ngerman` language option) and `ngerman`. In fact, since the `ngerman` package is deprecated, don't load it at all.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 5):

`biblatex` options cannot be set locally at the moment (see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1209 and specifically for dates https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/863), so if you don't want to change the format of other dates, you have to use some tricks. One trick would be to use a slightly more internal macro to print the ISO-formatted date.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ieee]{biblatex}

\newbibmacro*{isodate}{%
  \mkdaterangeiso{}%
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{norm}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printfield{type}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit*{\addcolon}%
  \usebibmacro{isodate}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isrn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@norm{lnorm,
  title   = {Information und Dokumentation
             -- Richtlinien für Titelangaben und Zitierung von Informationsressourcen},
  type    = {DIN ISO},
  number  = 690,
  date    = {2013-10},
  doi     = {10.31030/2054156},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Text~\cite[6]{lnorm}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: DIN ISO 690:2013-10, Information und Dokumentation – Richtlinien für Titelangaben und Zitierung von Informationsressourcen. doi: 10.31030/2054156.]

Comment: Why not use the `\mkdaterangeiso{}` directly, but encapsulate it in the extra function `\newbibmacro*{isodate}`?

Comment: @Dux No particular reason other than that I usually prefer my drivers to call only bibmacros as that makes things slightly easier to tweak later on. (Plus, it's analogous to what other drivers would do: they'd call the `date` bibmacro or a related bibmacro.)